# How to add credentials with ssh-add once, and have all shells thereonin authenticated

Tags: linux, ssh

I am looking for a way to add my passphrase to `ssh-agent` using `ssh-add` once, and from thereonin, if I open a new shell to the machine where that `ssh-agent` is running, have my credentials previously added available, so I don't need to continually call `ssh-add`.

---

I am connecting from my home computer to a work vm over a vpn.

My work vm's ssh key has a passphrase, and I am finding I need to enter the passphrase in every shell I open, no matter if I've already added it using `ssh-add` in another shell.

On startup, the work vm is running ssh-agent:

```
$ ps -ef | grep ssh-agent
steve       1594    1537  0 17:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /etc/X11/xinit/Xclients
steve       2686    2633  0 17:29 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ssh-agent
```

However, the connection details are not present in my environment:

```
$ env | grep SSH
SSH_CONNECTION=10.0.20.73 40232 10.10.0.123 22
SSH_CLIENT=10.0.20.73 40232 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
```

If I run `eval $(ssh-agent)`, then I have a 2nd `ssh-agent` running, and the connection details for the 2nd instance are present in my environment:

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent)
Agent pid 2705

$ ps -ef | grep ssh-agent
steve       1594    1537  0 17:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /etc/X11/xinit/Xclients
steve       2705       1  0 17:31 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
steve       2726    2633  0 17:31 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ssh-agent

$ env | grep SSH
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-ScGSgVMvxvS3/agent.2704
SSH_AGENT_PID=2705
SSH_CONNECTION=10.0.20.73 40232 10.10.0.123 22
SSH_CLIENT=10.0.20.73 40232 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
```

I **can** now successfully add my passphrase to the agent using `ssh-add`.

```
$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /home/steve/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/steve/.ssh/id_rsa (steve@vm-foobar)
```

However, if I open a new shell connection to my work vm, I am back at square one again

```
$ ssh vm-foobar
Last login: Mon Aug  3 17:29:49 2020 from 10.0.20.73

$ env | grep SSH
SSH_CONNECTION=10.0.20.73 40306 10.10.0.123 22
SSH_CLIENT=10.0.20.73 40306 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/2

$ ssh-add
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Is it possible to configure my bash profile etc on my work vm so that if I add my passphrase in one shell, it will work if I open a new shell?

Comment: May be that this page has the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155308/provide-passphrase-to-git-in-bash-script

Comment: @vssher thanks for the suggestion but no, I cant put my passphrase in my bashrc. I would like to `ssh-add` just once, and have all my shells from thereonin be authenticated